# How to create a string using placeholder (%s) in c

Tags: c

Normally we can use placeholder %s in printf(), fprintf() function.

I want to use placeholder to create a string using %s. Like that

```
 char fName[200] = "C:\\Users\\%s\\Desktop\\Result", getenv("USERNAME");

 // getenv() function will return current user name

 // The fName will be "C:\\Users\\Zobayer\\Desktop\\Result"
```

I know in c++ we can create it by stringstream

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "C:\\Users\\" << getenv("USERNAME") << "\\Desktop\\Result";
```

But In C how can i create this type of string ? Please help me.

And advance thanks from me.

Comment: `char fName[200]; snprintf(fName, sizeof(fName), "C:\\Users\\%s\\Desktop\\Result", getenv("USERNAME"));`

Comment: You need to use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, unless we can find a duplicate, that comment deserves to be promoted to an answer.

Comment: @RSahu Does this site need even a basic tutorial?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, creating tutorials not a charter of this site.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), instead of `sprintf`. It'll prevent the possible buffer overflow.

```
char fName[200];
snprintf(fName, sizeof(fName), "C:\\Users\\%s\\Desktop\\Result", getenv("USERNAME"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [sprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf). It would print to a string.

```
char fName[200];
sprintf(fName, "C:\\Users\\%s\\Desktop\\Result", getenv("USERNAME"));
```

Comment: Better use `snprintf`, not `sprintf`. This can overflow.

Comment: @Leandros Using `snprintf()` and not checking its result is not better than `sprintf()` - just trades one set of problems for another.  Robust code would check the result of `getenv()`, and size `fName[]` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

In C, code needs to handle memory allocation for the resultant string.  Many approaches.

```
// char fName[200] = "C:\\Users\\%s\\Desktop\\Result", getenv("USERNAME");

char *username = getenv("USERNAME");

// Insure a valid name was found
if (username == NULL) {
  Handle_NoUsername();
} 

// Allocate enough space for the answer
const char *format = "C:\\Users\\%s\\Desktop\\Result";
size_t size = strlen(format) + strlen(username) + 1;  // slight over-sized
char *fName = malloc(size);
if (fname == NULL) {
  Handle_OOM(); // Out-of-memory
}

int n = snprintf(fName, size, format, username);
if (n < 0 || n >= size) {
  Handle_UnusualPrintProblem();
}

// use fName

free(fName);
```